# Resize shape according to cell data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to resize the shape of rectangle according to cell data, were height(width) of rectangle is constant and length changes according to cell References.

For EG (please refer image) : DW1 is starting side which should have Reference data from range("B13") and move along or match data to range("D4:AF4") and it should be same for another end side DW2.
DW2 should have reference from range("C13") and match data to range("D4:AF4").

[image]

I have worked on some code but it is not having proper output.

Please have a look for my code below.

new code will also be helpfull

```
Sub Rectanglematch()
Dim dl1 As Double
Dim dl2 As Double
Dim dw1 As Double
Dim dw2 As Double
Dim dw As Double
Dim dl As Double
Dim d As Date
Dim R As Excel.Range

dw = dw1
dw = dw2
dl = dl1
dl = dl2

d = CDate(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("b13"))
Set R = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("d4:AF4")
dl1 = 10 * Range("A1").Value
dl2 = 10 * Range("A1").Value

dw1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(CDate(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("b13"))), R, 0)
dw2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(CDate(Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("c13"))), R, 0)
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rechteck 2")
        .Top = .Top - dw + .Height
        .Height = dw
        .Width = dl
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `dw = dw1
dw = dw2
dl = dl1
dl = dl2` neither dl1, dl2, dw1 nor dw2 are initialized. What are the point of setting dw and dl? and why twice?

Comment: Instead of calculating the width, have you considered using `Range.Left` and `Range.Width` to get the positions based on the cells?  (i.e. `.Left = R.Cells(1,db1).Left` and `.Width = R.Cells(1,db2).Left + R.Cells(1,db2).Width - R.Cells(1,db1).Left`)

Comment: Also db1 and db2 are undefined. And dl1 and dl2 are never used after being set.

Comment: sorry but i am new to vba , as i thought that i will use match for dw1 and dw2 to R ; and dl1 and dl2 are constant so i dont changed anything for both. it will be great help if you have new code.

Comment: @Chronocidal hey it worked absolutely correct as i wanted . Can we use the below code and variable using your calculation. Means using below logic case ie. for and next , LastRow and LastCol . i tried using above formula in below code , but i was not able to tackle the error. can you please use it and post your code as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I got your point in 100%, but take a look at my approach to this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rectanglematch()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim heightCell As Long
Dim widthCell As Long
Dim rngDates As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim sDat As Long
Dim eDat As Long
Dim myRectangle As Shape

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 6 To lastRow

        If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Or .Cells(i, 3) = "" Then

        Else
            heightCell = .Cells(i, 2).RowHeight
            widthCell = .Cells(i, 2).Width

            Set rngDates = .Range(.Cells(4, 4), .Cells(4, lastCol))

            sDat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 2), rngDates, 0) + 3
            eDat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 3), rngDates, 0) + 3

            Set myRectangle = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, .Cells(i, sDat).Left, .Cells(i, sDat).Top, .Cells(i, eDat).Left - .Cells(i, sDat).Left, heightCell)
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Hope it will help You :)

Comment: hey i tried using it, i got some problems i.e., when i expand any cell it doesn't take any Reference from it, EG: expand column P and then also the result is same, but as now it should take the reference of it and end at the shape at the column P. and one more if there is blank row in middle it gets MATCH error. can you help me this problem

Comment: What do You mean by saying "expand"?

Comment: Ok, I modified width parameter of rectangle from `(eDat - sDat) * widthCell` to this `.Cells(i, eDat).Left - .Cells(i, sDat).Left`, check it now :) I also checked my sheet with empty header and its working ok, can You explain it more if it is still the case?

Comment: Super. Working Perfectly. Any idea for empty Cell or if there is only data in one cell and not in the next cell. EG : B11 = "JAN 20" and C11 = "Empty". If there is only one input then it should not show rectangle and must go to another row.

Comment: Because for every single data i am going to use it as milestone. EG: B11 : Jan 20; which should show triangle in center of cell D11 (JAN 20) using match from Range(D4:AF4). that is my next task. It will be great help if you helpme out. and nothing to be shown if both are empty.

Comment: I already edited code. Added conditional which will skip row if there is no date in column B or C. Check now :) Create new question for this task with triangle :)

Comment: ok Thanks . it is now working but when i don´t have data in column C ; it is still showing MATCH ERROR. and every time i run the code i need to delete first every shape which is already there. Is there any code which will help me for it(somewhat refresh or delete old shapes); if there is already shape there for that cell first delete it and have new one created after every run.

Comment: Sure i will create new questions for New Task. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Or in simple word i want to replace those shape every time i run the program.

Comment: Did You tried version of code with `If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Or .Cells(i, 3) = "" Then` conditional? That will skip rows when column B or C is empty. So there can't be MATCH ERROR :)

Comment: yeah its working thanks. and for replace i have used `For Each myRectangle In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  If myRectangle.Type <> msoChart And myRectangle.Type <> msoComment Then myRectangle.Delete
Next myRectangle`